# If date time == 01:01:01

Tags: c#

I get a date from a database and want to check if it is equal to a specific date. HOw can I do this.

i have tried

```
if (date == 01:01:0001)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Cheers

Comment: This is basic syntax, get a good book before you open a compiler.

Comment: `:` as a _date seperator_? What is your culture? And your question is too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (date == new DateTime(2001, 12, 5)) { ... }
```